# Agoda rest api issue.. unable to get response from agoda api

Tags: api

i am trying to get the hotel lists from the agoda api.. but always end up with this :

The request's Content-Type is not supported. Expected:
application/xml or text/xml or application/json

[image]

Comment: You need to change the value of the "Content-Type" key in headers to "application/xml" or "application/json".

Comment: yes.. i changed and tried with both.. but no difference..

Answer (score 1):

In postman: Set the headers like this first-
[image]

then set the body under raw(json)-
[image]

You should get the response like this on send-
[image]